# How to fetch device list from my database when linked my skill using LWA in aws lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, login-with-amazon, alexa-smart-home-skill

I had linked my smart home skill using LWA **'Login with Amazon'**. It is working perfectly. My question is how to fetch the device list which is stored in my database. I get the bearer token for each directive call. But I don't know how to use that **bearer token** to get the **device list** from my database during **Discovery directive**.

I have my own smart home app where the user creates account and login to get the device list. User adds a device via my app.

Answer (score 0):

For fetching your data from your database assuming you are using AWS RDS you can use 
the AWS Lambda service.

Try this link:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/query-your-aws-database-from-your-serverless-application/#Step_6._Query[Query your AWS database from your serverless application][1]